# Proof about sum of convex polygon interior angles

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I'm working through Richard Hamming's "Methods of Mathematics Applied to Calculus, Probability, and Statistics" on my own.

I'm struggling with this proof (clipped from Google books):

[image]

I follow him all the way until the last sentence (starting with "Thus we have...").

Could someone perhaps take a stab at translating/paraphrasing that rather clunky final sentence, which is the punchline?

(Frustrating that he's so careful and deliberate with the rest of the paragraph (e.g., "This forms a triangle.") while he uses an overly complex sentence at the end to reveal the moral of the story.)

Comment: It can easily be reframed as ordinary induction. The author chose the minimal criminal version.

Comment: I am just adding a different approach. Take an interior point and connect it with all $n$ vertices of the $n$-gon. Notice that $n$ triangles were formed. The sum of the angles of these triangles is $n\cdot 180^{\circ}$. Now the only thing left to do is to subtract the sum of the angles around the interior point we chose, which is $2\cdot 180^{\circ}$. So the formula $(n-2)\cdot 180^{\circ}$ is established.

Comment: Usually with induction we assume $S_k$ to be true, and show that $S_{k+1}$ must also be true. If $S_0$ is true, then all statements must be true. Hamming combines induction with proof by contradiction by assuming that for some $n$, $S_n$ is false. He then shows that $S_{n-1}$ must be false as well, which implies that $S_0$ must also be false, which is a contradiction because  $S_0$ is the statement that a triangle has $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. My question still stands...

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I've never heard the phrase "minimal criminal" before (whether in this connection or otherwise), but I'm really diggin' it.

Comment: @BrianTung: I did not invent it, have seen it a number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can state the argument in the following way.  Following the general lines of John Joy's comment:

- Suppose we had a polygon of $n > 3$ sides that failed to have $180(n-2)$ internal degrees.  (A triangle cannot fail to have $180$ internal degrees, by assumption.)
- From that polygon, by shaving off a wedge as depicted in the diagram above, we can produce a new polygon of $n-1$ sides that fails to have $180(n-3)$ internal degrees.
- There is no immediate contradiction here, but we eventually must get to a point where we can go no further: We end up with a polygon of $4$ sides that fails to have $360$ degrees.  From this, by the above argument, we can produce a polygon of $3$ sides that fails to have $180$ degrees.  But we have decreed that this cannot happen.
- Thus, our original assumption—that we could have a polygon of $n$ sides that fails to have $180(n-2)$ internal degrees—must be in error.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a convoluted way to describe induction on $n$.

In the first part he proves the following: If we have a convex $n$-gon for which the sum of the angles is $S$, then we can construct an $(n - 1)$-gon for which the sum of the angles is $K - 180^\circ$.

Now this $(n - 1)$-gon can again be reduced to an $(n - 2)$-gon for which the sum of the angles is $K - 2 \cdot 180^\circ$. This step can be repeated until we reach a $3$-gon, i.e. a triangle. The sum of its angles must be $K - (n - 3) \cdot 180^\circ$.

If we now assume $K \ne (n - 2) \cdot 180^\circ$, then the sum of the angles in the triangle isn't equal to $(n - 2) \cdot 180^\circ - (n - 3) \cdot 180^\circ = 180^\circ$. But this is a contradiction, so the formula $K = (n - 2) \cdot 180^\circ$ must be true.